# Is it possible for a UNIX/Linux shell script to 'exit' and log out the current user?

Tags: unix, shell, scripting, aix

We're having a strange issue here. Unfortunately I'm not at liberty to post the code here because it belongs to the vendor, but hopefully can provide enough info so that isn't necessary.

Much could be explained if someone here could definitively say whether or not it is possible for 'bob' to execute "some_script.sh", and have it exit out of his su'd session MID-WAY and have the remainder of the script continue as user 'pete' (who originally su'd to impersonate 'bob')

I'm fairly certain that this is not possible, but is there anyone out there that knows otherwise?

Things to keep in mind:

1. scriptA.sh executes multiple other processes (serially) which make changes to a database

   - lets assume that these are 01.sql through to 10.sql.
   - It does this by executing 'sqlplus' with appropriate arguments.
2. The 'sqlplus' binary is available to user 'bob', but NOT user 'pete'.
3. User pete is currently su'd into user 'bob', because pete doesn't have sqlplus on his PATH.
4. The output we saw in the script/database suggested that the '01.sql' was executed successfully, but not the others - they failed with a 'sqlplus command not found' error.

Cheers,

Comment: Is that the only reason he su'd? Just `slocate sqlplus |grep bin` and add that to the path

Comment: Wow fast response :) Unfortunately that's not an option for us - 'bob' is actually a functional user with all the necessary permissions and path aliases set up to execute 'sqlplus' amongst other things, and he's shared by several users.

Comment: Then it seems you've already discovered the problem. pete is incapable of executing sqlplus, and if the shell script wants him to, there are problems. Why can't bob run the whole thing?

Comment: Clarification: we *want* bob to run the whole thing, however on our last run we've observed some strange behaviour - i.e. the first part of the script was executed successfully, but the second part of the script had 'sqlplus not found' errors. Some colleagues are suggesting that the script could have exited out 'bob' mid-way, and ran the remainder of the script as 'pete'... but I don't think that's possible, and don't want to spend time barking up the wrong tree on this script... Which brought me here to ask the question - is this possible?

Comment: so you `su bob` or `su - bob` if the former, you might be using pete's environment, and only bob's name.

Comment: Few things are impossible, but mystically switching paths within a script that you can read is really, really unlikely. Stick a `which sqlplus ; echo $PATH` before the offending line. Note that your error is ENOENT *not* EPERM.

Comment: Given no knee-jerk "Yes of course" answers, your answers collectively seem to suggest that it's HIGHLY UNLIKELY for $PATH or UID to mysteriously change during script execution. There are no strange constructs in this script, so we can probably conclude that it's more likely that this was a user execution error - nothing strange like a UID switching half way through the script as some here have suspected. I haven't been able to reproduce the error at all (someone else initially ran it, I'm merely investigating via logs). Thanks all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the information you've given, "No. It is not possible."

If user 'pete' `su`'s to 'bob', he creates a new shell as 'bob'. Any processes started from that new shell are run as 'bob'. Any script, if run as 'bob', cannot change it's user/UID to 'pete'. Any processes started as 'bob' cannot change their user/UID (absent setuid bit on the executable).

It's far more likely that part of the script is modifying the shell environment and changing its PATH or some other error within the script.

Comment: Excellent - thanks for the answer. The going consensus over here at the office was that the script may somehow have had one too many exit commands, so was switching users... but I was certain that no matter how many exit commands are in a script (despite a `trap "exit 1" ....`), this just fundamentally is not possible. Your answer along with the other comments confirms my understanding, and that the issue lies elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Using a script to attempt to switch UIDs is doomed to failure. A permissions system that requires shared logins is – by definition – insecure.

Use the AIX permissions system the way it was intended. If you need bob's credentials to perform a task then have a program that Sandipan can execute which will elevate to bob permissions for only that which needs bob's credentials.

This is the [Principle of Least Privilege](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege) and is how to handle the job. Shared passwords are a bad hack that encourages worse hacks.

Comment: Thanks for the input, and I agree with what you're saying 100% - I would never write a script that way.... But just to clarify, this isn't a question on what is a good/bad design. We need to know whether or not it is *at all* possible for a script to switch UID's on AIX - inadvertently or otherwise - half way through the script. This is for my own curiosity for whether or not this is even possible, and to aid in our investigation.